# How to send random file from folder

Tags: nginx

I want to create an nginx file server. The main criteria is sending a random file from defined folder on the machine. It's no matter what is a URL user will trying to open.

How to send random file ?
Can I set it up inside nginx.conf ?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_random_index_module.html. This module must have been enabled at build time with `--with-http_random_index_module`.